# Gate Gazetteer vs. Grammar v8.1 (virtualization)

Tags: gate

I tired to find list entries via different Gazetteers (also used some Cerole plugins), for instance 'Data Quality'. However, when using the gazetteer on a test set like:
_
Data Quality.
data quality.
accuracy and quality of data.
high quality data.
_

Only the first two entries are found. Clearly, i would like to find all entries in the above mentioned test set. The question is if my problem is solveable with a gazetteers or if grammar rules are needed for this purpose. I wasn't able to find an answer under the literature suggested term 'virtualization'.

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

Gazetteers (usually) just match the words in the lists. You should either add all of those forms to a gazetteer list or combine with grammar rules, to handle "quality of data", "quality of the data", etc.

Perhaps the real issue you're having is how to build the right dictionaries - it's hard and it's out of GATE, at least in my experience :)

For the dictionaries you should check dictionaries with synonyms, virtualization-specific terms is specialized websites, dbpedia/LOD-like repositories with terms etc.

Also take a look at brown clusters, topic modelling, word2vec maybe you can find or build the right synonym phrases with those tools.